# Custom buttonbar with overflow menu in Android

Tags: android, menu

In my app, I want to show some buttons in a `LinearLayout` that expands over whole width of the screen. Depending on screen size and/or orientation, I would like to hide those buttons, that don't fit in the row, in some `OverflowMenu`, similar to the behaviour of the `ActionBar`. If possible, I would like to describe the buttons in a `menu resource file` with the `ifRoom|always` attributes.

I considered displaying a `Toolbar` from the latest `AppCompat` library, but that contains too many elements that I don't need and don't know how to turn off.

Is there some library or simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example to do what you want. Make sure your ActionMenuView XML item is wrap_content for height and width, then gravity to the right. Surround it in a LinearLayout which takes the whole width and provides background color.

Use this code to initialize the ActionMenuView (obviously you will need to change the button callbacks)

```
        ActionMenuView actionMenuView = (ActionMenuView) findViewById(R.id.editBar);

        final Context context = this;
        MenuBuilder menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(context);
        menuBuilder.setCallback(new MenuBuilder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menuBuilder, MenuItem menuItem) {
                return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menuBuilder) {

            }
        });

        // setup a actionMenuPresenter which will use up as much space as it can, even with width=wrap_content
        ActionMenuPresenter presenter = new ActionMenuPresenter(context);
        presenter.setReserveOverflow(true);
        presenter.setWidthLimit(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, true);
        presenter.setItemLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // open a menu xml into the menubuilder
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.editbar, menuBuilder);

        // runs presenter.initformenu(mMenu) too, setting up presenter's mmenu ref...  this must be before setmenuview
        menuBuilder.addMenuPresenter(presenter, this);

        // runs menuview.initialize too, so menuview.mmenu = mpresenter.mmenu
        actionMenuView.setPresenter(presenter);

        presenter.updateMenuView(true);
```

For what it's worth, I had to read the support library source code for 8 hours to get this to work. The documentation is garbage.

Comment: as an update of this answer: Moving to appcompat 23.1.1 I had to hack a bit the imports, and it seems that ActionMenuPresenter is now package local...  
So I had to create a android.support.v7.widget package in my project and add a PublicActionMenuPresenter class as follow:  
    `public class PublicActionMenuPresenter extends ActionMenuPresenter {
        public PublicActionMenuPresenter(Context context) {
            super(context);
       }`  
and use that instead of ActionMenuPresenter

Answer (score 4):

[ActionMenuView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ActionMenuView.html) is the part of a [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) which specifically controls the actions and overflow part of the Toolbar. In your case, you can use an `ActionMenuView` alone to implement just the actions/overflow part of the Toolbar:

1. Add an `ActionMenuView` to the appropriate place in your XML layout
2. Retrieve a [MenuInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html) (easiest way is through an Activity's [getMenuInflater()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getMenuInflater()) method
3. Call `menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, actionMenuView.getMenu())` to inflate your menu into the `ActionMenuView`

Comment: That does sound perfect. However, while I can see some buttons next to the overflow Menu button using the Toolbar, I can't see anything if I change `Toolbar` into `ActionMenuView`. There is no error or anything, simply empty space where the menu should be displayed.

Comment: Make sure your ActionMenuView is given at least 56x56dp of space. Seems to be a bug with the current version if given a smaller space than that it won't display anything

Comment: Right, now I am seeing something - it only works, when its width is not `match_parent` but, for example, `wrap_content`. If it is the latter, than I only see two buttons and those three dots for the overflow button, just as it appears in the `Toolbar`. Is there anything I could hack to make it become wider and display more buttons? (It shows one more button in landscape mode :) )

Comment: I am still stuck with this. I tried copying the `ActionMenuView` into my project and debug it myself, but I couldn't find what's going wrong. Could you give me a hint on how to patch this behaviour? /e: Apparently, the bug has already been filed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78364